# How do I get actual file size in C# or PowerShell for a file that is opened by another process?

Tags: c#, powershell

I recently have a project need to monitor a file growth to prevent file exceed its limits.
There is file is opened by another process. The process continue to add contents to this file.
I need to monitor its file size to make sure it is not more than 64GB for its file size.
Because file is opened and writing, Get-ChildItem or [System.IO.FileInfo] can't get its actual file size.
Also, the file size will not update if I refresh in Windows Explorer. I have to right click the file and select Properties. Then the file size is updated.

Just wondering how do I get the actual file size if the file is opened and writing by other process?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: _need to monitor a file growth to prevent file exceed its limits_:  And what are you going to do about it? The application that is creating/writing to the file should take care of managing the file size. There's not much you can do for managing a file's size if another program has locked the file for writing. Unless you plan to terminate the other program, trim the file, and restart the other program.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could try using the System.IO.FileStream class to open the file with FileShare.ReadWrite access, which allows you to read the file even if it is currently being written to by another process (C# and PowerShell).

<------------------------------------------------------------>

For C#:

```
using System.IO;

string filePath = @"C:\path\to\file.txt";
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    long fileSize = stream.Length;
    // fileSize now contains the actual file size, even if the file is opened and writing by another process
}
```

<------------------------------------------------------------>

For PowerShell:

```
$filePath = "C:\path\to\file.txt"
$fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($filePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
$fileSize = $fileStream.Length
$fileStream.Close()
# $fileSize now contains the actual file size, even if the file is opened and writing by another process
```

Remember to close the file stream when you're done with it, so that other processes can access the file if necessary. Maybe that's the reason why you have to right click the file and select Properties? I don't know.

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks! It took me a long time to get back this question because of some other reason.  And I just tried your suggestion. Don't know why the file cannot access because it is being used by another process. The same method to access a growing NSF (Domino database) file is good. But not for a ZIP file. This project is continue to pack some files into a ZIP file or NSF file. It just can't get the actual file size for ZIP file only.

Comment: Best of luck Ivan. Day's can be challenges,  I know. Remember to upvote if it help you. Cheers!